# How to Get Maven to Fail on Deploy when warned about "CHECKSUM FAILED"

Tags: maven-2, warnings, deployment, nexus

On maven deploy maven attempts to retrieve the previous metadata form the repository.  If it is corrupt maven issues a warning, calls the build successful but doesn't upload my artifact.  This was caused by corruption in my repository and I'd like to either avoid it in future or make it more obvious with a build failure.

Can I alter my pom to change this warning into an error so I'll see it quickly?

`[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from daeng-snap
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = 'ea12f35b3bc6d88f7336891562d91985b412bf1a'; remote = '51a6f4a52ad8f3926dbb28807317a90b9cd62ec1' - RETRYING
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = 'ea12f35b3bc6d88f7336891562d91985b412bf1a'; remote = '51a6f4a52ad8f3926dbb28807317a90b9cd62ec1' - IGNORING
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'artifact com.myco.xyz'
[INFO] Uploading project information for xyz 5.0.2-20091224.163241-12
[INFO] Retrieving previous metadata from snaphots
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '00766e1a0130c3499442c06b52523960c5860f3c'; remote = 'c9bcfc92b3145688aa8ec77dcac244c70be4d0b4' - RETRYING
[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '00766e1a0130c3499442c06b52523960c5860f3c'; remote = 'c9bcfc92b3145688aa8ec77dcac244c70be4d0b4' - IGNORING
[INFO] Uploading repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.myco.xyz:xyz:5.0.2-SNAPSHOT'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fail your build due to a bad checksum. Simply configure your repository element - preferably in your settings.xml or inside your repository manager such as nexus.

Example:

```
<repository>
  <id>central</id>
  <name>My Central Repository</name>
  <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
  <releases>
    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
  </releases>
  <snapshots>
    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
  </snapshots>
</repository>
```

More info here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/appendix-settings-sect-settings-repository.html

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  I've set it in my settings file and configured nexus.xml to set the repository policy to fail.  In both cases the build is still successful

[WARNING] *** CHECKSUM FAILED - Checksum failed on download: local = '24dab9a242e9e9399cc79221b8ed47af31a37a0f'; remote = '55aac6492bc939be75438399ba6b6002fc0cf3d6bc' - IGNORING

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. It works only when I use `--strict-checksums` (or `-C`) when I execute my Maven command. Also it seems like that there is no check when you have the artifact in your local Maven repository (no matter whether it is valid or not).